# How to convert 24/01/2023 into 2023-01-24

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime, exception, format

I tried converting the date by doing the below code

```
  DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')
              .add_yMMMd()
              .parse((state as SlotRequestPopUpDataLoadedState).date)
              .toString(),
        );
```

But it throws error

```
Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Trying to read - from 09/01/2023 at position 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this issue because you are trying to parse a date that contains `-` but your date contains `/`. Let's say this is your date:

```
var date = '24/01/2023';
```

you can convert it like this:

```
var Dtime = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').parse(date);

print('newDate = ${DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(Dtime)}'); //newDate = 2023-01-24
```

Comment: Using `replaceAll` is silly.  Just use `/` in the format string used for parsing.